# test function whenstable of angular2 didn't wait for promise resloves

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I'm using `SystemJsModuleLoader` to load modules, it works just fine.
But when I test my app, `whenStable` didn't works as it describes.
It resolves so fast that `systemjsLoader.load()` hasn't resolved yet.
So I can't do test in `whenStable().then(my test here...)`.

My questions are:

1. Why the `whenStable` doesn't wait the promise resolves?
   https://plnkr.co/edit/E438ngPcFYkwh48CTUoe?p=preview (VERSION1)
2. And why the `whenStable` works just fine when I put the code from `onClick` to `ngOnInit`?
   https://plnkr.co/edit/E438ngPcFYkwh48CTUoe?p=preview (VERSION2)

I have already opened a issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20774), but I don't think this is a `<script>` ordering problem since I use the example the angular.io provided, and I want to try some luck here.

Comment: have you tried `fakeAsync {} -- tick()`?

Comment: I have tried `fakeAsync`, but didn't work, still failed. @LucaTaccagni